# Is there a way to assemble contigs starting from a specific sequence?

Tags: sequence-alignment, fasta, assembly, metagenome

My work involves searching for marker genes/fragments in metagenomic databases (like the Sequence Read Archive). Once I find these sequences, I would like to know more about the neighboring genomic region.

Is there a way I could assemble only sequences that create a contig which contains my region of interest? Contigs which don't contain this region are not useful to me. My organism of interest might represent a minority of the metagenome, and assembling everything in the dataset would use a lot of computing power.

Comment: Good question! I know that some of the assemblers for mtDNA are working on this principle - searching for reads mapping to a conserved mt gene and then extending the sequence, maybe you could tweak one of those tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the primary use cases for which spacegraphcats ([preprint](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/462788v2) and [code](https://github.com/spacegraphcats/spacegraphcats)) was designed. The "neighborhood queries" discussed in the paper sound particularly relevant. I don't have any personal experience with spacegraphcats, but the [run guide](https://github.com/spacegraphcats/spacegraphcats/blob/master/doc/running-spacegraphcats.md) provides some examples of how to index the complete data set and how to query sequences of interest.

Comment: Yes, we'd be happy to chat (I'm one of the spacegraphcats authors). Just post questions over on our github repo!

Comment: You might also be interested in citations 21 and 22 in the spacegraphcats paper - metacherchant and a paper that does something similar.